# overriding onDrop event breaking ImageInput preview

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, react-dropzone

I am trying to override `onDrop()` in `<ImageInput>` but it fails when file is uploaded. It don't show image preview.

The Following is component.
I am calling a api which will return me url and I am setting to state, for further purpose.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ImageInput, ImageField } from 'react-admin';

import service from '../../providers/service';

class ImageUpload extends Component {
  onDropChange = (files) => {
    const file = new FormData();
    file.append('image', files[0]);
    service('post', 'upload', file)
      .then((response) => {
        response.data.partner_logo_url = response.data.url;
        this.props.onPartnerLogo(response.data.url);
        return response;
      });
  };

  render() {
    const { source, validate, label } = this.props;

    return (
      <ImageInput
        source={source}
        validate={validate}
        label={label}
        accept="image/*"
        options={{
          onDrop: this.onDropChange,
        }}
      >
        <ImageField source="src"/>
      </ImageInput>
    );
  }
}

export default ImageUpload;
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue.

I tried onChange instead of onDrop, and that shows the preview correctly.  Unfortunately, onChange only triggers if I click on the image loader and load the image from the file dialog. It doesn't trigger when I drag and drop the image file from the Finder.  (That was on Mac OS X Mojave.)  So that wasn't much use to me.

In the end I worked around it by dropping the ImageField component altogether and just using an ordinary img tag.  I then use the onDrop callback to set the src of that img tag to the preview property of fileObj parameter that's passed to the callback.

```
const ImageForm = props => {
  const [previewPath, setPreviewPath] = useState("");

  const handleImageChange = fileObj => {
    setPreviewPath(fileObj[0].preview);
  };

  return (
    <SimpleForm {...props}>
      <ImageInput
        source="pictures"
        label="Image"
        accept="image/*"
        options={{ onDrop: handleImageChange }}
      />
      {previewPath && previewPath !== "" ? (
        <img
          src={previewPath}
          title="preview"
          alt="preview"
        />
      ) : null}
    </SimpleForm>
  );
};
```

Note: the img tag has to go outside of the ImageInput component - i.e. *not* as a child of it - or it won't work.